# interpreting xml produced by microsoft office word and excel documents

Tags: xml, excel, vba, ms-word

I wish to build a free system to extract the text, text formatting (e.g bold etc) and images contents inside documents such as excel and word.

In my research I have found that the structure of excel (xlsx) and word (docx) documents is defined in xml once you extract the document with a compression utility like 7zip.

I am skilled in VBA, however I have not been able to find an object model (listing ALL objects and methods that can be applied /manipulated for any of:

1. Excel VBA
2. Word VBA
3. Word XML
4. Excel XML

I know many excel vba objects already however that is just through trial and error and experimentation, and not through reading an object model where the methods/objects are defined!

**The problem**

- **I don't know how to interpret the XML because I don't have an object model showing me that  **and**  means bold etc**

I am trying to develop a tool which looks through the xml to find:

1. The location of any images in the document, both the relative directory (in the Directory / Word / Media folder) and the actual file path, e.g. C:\documents\josh\img1.png
2. The position of any text in the document (I'm thinking in terms of lines, reading a document from top to bottom, as well as alignment like centre etc) SO I can reproduce the text in the right order.
3. The formatting applied to the text (bold, some font, some size?

Please help me find an object model or some way to interpret or parse this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="001920B6" w:rsidRDefault="001920B6" w:rsidP="001920B6"><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:drawing><wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="4B104522" wp14:editId="4A3907E9"><wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/><wp:positionH relativeFrom="column"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH><wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph"><wp:posOffset>1209675</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV><wp:extent cx="5943600" cy="3343275"/><wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="9525"/><wp:wrapTight wrapText="bothSides"><wp:wrapPolygon edited="0"><wp:start x="0" y="0"/><wp:lineTo x="0" y="21538"/><wp:lineTo x="21531" y="21538"/><wp:lineTo x="21531" y="0"/><wp:lineTo x="0" y="0"/></wp:wrapPolygon></wp:wrapTight><wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:nvPicPr><pic:cNvPr id="0" name="windows.png"/><pic:cNvPicPr/></pic:nvPicPr><pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId7" cstate="print"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"><a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:blip><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></pic:blipFill><pic:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="5943600" cy="3343275"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom></pic:spPr></pic:pic></a:graphicData></a:graphic><wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="page"><wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth></wp14:sizeRelH><wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="page"><wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight></wp14:sizeRelV></wp:anchor></w:drawing></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00327DB9"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>Plain text</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00327DB9" w:rsidRDefault="00327DB9" w:rsidP="001920B6"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>bold</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="0009704D" w:rsidRPr="00327DB9"><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> text</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00327DB9" w:rsidRPr="00327DB9" w:rsidRDefault="00327DB9" w:rsidP="00327DB9"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>heading</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00327DB9" w:rsidRPr="001920B6" w:rsidRDefault="00327DB9"/><w:sectPr w:rsidR="00327DB9" w:rsidRPr="001920B6"><w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="720"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```

**Questions about the xml**

1. Determining the position of the image (which is at the bottom) relative to the text (which is above it)
2. How many images there are? Is there one because the picture has an ID or INDEX of 0?

Comment: Pleas add more info about what that extracted data will be used for. (My intuition would be to use anything BUT VBA, but You still may have some good reason)

Comment: the data (text and images inside) could be used for anything, such as save to web, extract only data (maybe I don't need all the formatting)

Comment: @– przemo_li do you know where the VBA object model is?

Comment: In VBA? You can open any Excel file user can pick. Then: ThisWorkbook.VBAProject. ... But be aware that require Extensibility library set in References, and setting permission in macro security settings. And AV software can still block such behavior :D Anyway. I do not think that VBA is right tool for general purpose OOXML slicing and patching.

Comment: @– przemo_li, YES, I code in VBA, so I know how to get to the editor and set references via the tools menu. What I can't find online though is an object model. For example it might say>> Object: Workbook Method: Add Sheet, Basically I can't find anywhere that these methods and objects are all listed in one place?

Comment: ThisWorkbook. And then Tab in VBE. Myself I found that objects by reading code snippets. But generally everything should be somwhere inside ThisWorkbook (or other opened workbook). eg. ThisWorkbook.VBAProject.VBAComponents list all vba modules/classes/spreadsheets/etc.

Comment: c. – przemo_li >> I don't quite follow where this object model is stored inside VBA Editor? Could you upload a screenshot? I've learned everything reading the many code snippets out there too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50136/discussion-between-przemo-li-and-yoshiserry)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Office Open XML, that's the xml-structure of all MS-Office documents:
http://openxmldeveloper.org/.
There is a rahter good ebook which explains the basics: http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx

But bewarE: parsing or interpreting Office Open XML is a extremely huge task, especially in VBA which is ill-suited for this job.
There are numerous libraries in C# / VB.net which can read office open xml documents, which would be a better starting point.

Comment: is there one for python which is much faster?

Comment: Python faster than C#? maybe development bot not raw code-speed (I program in both....)
As for a python lib: google: python office openxml

Comment: where is the Ebook? I can't find it :(

Comment: is it possible using the zip folder structure to exract the VBA code in the different modules?

Comment: Yes, I think so. EPPLus has this capabillity - you could take a look on their code.

Comment: Christian, is there an actual object model written somewhere though? Like object, method, etc?

Comment: Take a look at the office open xml library...this is the closes think you will find.

Comment: JFYI.. the links are not accessible now.